# Error When Calculating Standard Deviation in PowerShell

Tags: csv, powershell, statistics, standard-deviation

I'm attempting to calculate some statistics for the values in each column of a CSV file using PowerShell. The Measure-Object cmdlet seems like it will do the trick for everything I need other than the Standard Deviation. I tracked down a description online where the Standard Deviation is calculated using [MATH], but when I run the code, I get the following error on the lines containing Pow():

> Method invocation failed because system.management.automation.psobject doesn't contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'.

Here's my code, any help would be appreciated:

```
$i = 1

While ($i -le 211) {

#Set the variable to the filename with the iteration number
$filename = "c:\zMFM\z550Output\20dSummer\fixed20dSum550Output$i.csv"


#Check to see if that a file with $filename exists. If not, skip to the next iteration of $i. If so, run the code to collect the statistics for each variable and output them each to a different file
If (Test-Path $filename) {


#Calculate the Standard Deviation
#First get the average of the values in the column
$STDEVInputFile = Import-CSV $filename

#Find the average and count for column 'td'
$STDEVAVG = $STDEVInputFile | Measure-Object td -Average | Select Count, Average
$DevMath = 0

# Sum the squares of the differences between the mean and each value in the array
Foreach ($Y in $STDEVInputFile) {
$DevMath += [math]::pow(($Y - $STDEVAVG.Average), 2)

#Divide by the number of samples minus one
$STDEV = [Math]::sqrt($DevMath / ($STDEVAVG.Count-1))

}

#Calculate the basic statistics for column 'td' with the MEASURE-OBJECT cmdlet
$STATS = Import-CSV $Filename |
Measure-Object td -ave -max -min

#Append the standard deviation variable to the statistics array and add the value

$colSTDDEV = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn StdDev,([double])
$colVZA = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn VZA,([double])
$colVAZ = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn VAZ,([double])


$VZA = $Stats.VZA
$VAZ = $Stats.VAZ


$STATS.Columns.Add($colSTDDEV)
$STATS[0].StandardDev = $STDEV


$STATS.Columns.Add($colVZA)
$STATS[0].StandardDev = $VZA


$STATS.Columns.Add($colVAZ)
$STATS[0].StandardDev = $VAZ

#Export the $STATS file containing everything you need in the correct folder


Export-CSV -notype "c:\zMFM\z550Output\20dSummer\20dSum550Statistics.csv"

}
$i++
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$DevMath += [math]::pow(($Y - $STDEVAVG.Average), 2)
```

You may have to replace this with:

```
$DevMath += [math]::pow(($Y.Average - $STDEVAVG.Average), 2)
```

since `$Y` seems to be an object, not a numeric value.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, at least in the sense that the error message disappeared.  
Now I'm having an issue where the program seems to hang, so I cannot see if the output is actually correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Before maybe posting another question :), try to comment and uncomment your code line by line to isolate the culprit, or use the debugger (https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd819480.aspx)